# WPF - How to force a Command to re-evaluate 'CanExecute' via its CommandBindings

Tags: .net, wpf, command, commandbinding

I have a `Menu` where each `MenuItem` in the hierarchy has its `Command` property set to a `RoutedCommand` I've defined.  The associated `CommandBinding` provides a callback for the evaluation of `CanExecute` which controls the enabled state of each `MenuItem`.

This *almost* works.  The menu items initially come up with the correct enabled and disabled states.  However when the data that my `CanExecute` callback uses changes, I need the command to re-request a result from my callback in order for this new state to be reflected in the UI.

There do not appear to be any public methods on `RoutedCommand` or `CommandBinding` for this.

Note that the callback is used again when I click or type into the control (I guess it's triggered on input because mouse-over doesn't cause the refresh).

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Not the prettiest in the book, but you can use the CommandManager to invalidate all commandbinding:

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

See more info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this worked just fine.  There's a slight delay in the UI, but I'm not too worried about that.  Also, I up-voted your answer immediately, then took the vote back to see whether it worked.  Now that it's working, I can't re-apply the vote again.  Not sure why SO has that rule in place.

Comment: I edited your answer in order to re-apply my vote.  I didn't change anything in the edit.  Thanks again.

Comment: I had the same problem happening when I was changing the content of a Texbox from the code-behind. If you edit it by hand it would work. In this app, they had the texbox being edited by a control that would popup, and when you saved the popup, it would change the Texbox.Text property. This solved the problem! Thanks @Arcturus

Comment: Just note from other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783104/refresh-wpf-command) "it has to be called on the UI thread"

Answer (score 89):

For anyone who comes across this later; If you happen to be using MVVM and Prism, then Prism's `DelegateCommand` implementation of `ICommand` provides a `.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method to do this.

Comment: This pattern is found in other MVVM libraries too, e.g. MVVM Light.

Comment: Unlike Prism, MVVM Light v5's source code indicates its `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`  simply calls `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`.

Comment: a side note to MVVM Light in WPF, you need to use the namespace GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf since GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command will cause trouble http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/changes#v5_0_2

Comment: `((RelayCommand)MyCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` worked for me, using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command - BUT after changing to `CommandWPF`, it worked without the need to call anything. Thanks @fuchs777

Comment: What if you aren't using a 3rd party library though?

Answer (score 32):

I couldnt use `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` because I was getting performance hit.

I have used [MVVM Helper](http://mvvmhelpers.codeplex.com/)'s Delegating command, which looks like below (i have tweaked it a bit for our req). you have to call `command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` from VM

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add
    {
        _internalCanExecuteChanged += value;
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        _internalCanExecuteChanged -= value;
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This method can be used to raise the CanExecuteChanged handler.
/// This will force WPF to re-query the status of this command directly.
/// </summary>
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    if (canExecute != null)
        OnCanExecuteChanged();
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is used to walk the delegate chain and well WPF that
/// our command execution status has changed.
/// </summary>
protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged()
{
    EventHandler eCanExecuteChanged = _internalCanExecuteChanged;
    if (eCanExecuteChanged != null)
        eCanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI I commented out CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; I was getting a near constant/looping evaluation of my CanExecute code for some reason. Otherwise the solution worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

If you have rolled your own class that implements `ICommand` you can lose a lot of the automatic status updates forcing you to rely on manual refreshing more than should be needed. It can also break `InvalidateRequerySuggested()`. The problem is that a simple `ICommand` implementation fails to link the new command to the `CommandManager`.

The solution is to use the following:

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
```

This way subscribers attach to `CommandManager` rather than your class and can properly participate in command status changes.

Comment: Straightforward, to the point, and allows people to have control over their ICommand implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a solution to handle property dependency on commands, here the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394333/1716620

thanks to that you'll end up having a command like this:

```
this.SaveCommand = new MyDelegateCommand<MyViewModel>(this,
    //execute
    () => {
      Console.Write("EXECUTED");
    },
    //can execute
    () => {
      Console.Write("Checking Validity");
       return PropertyX!=null && PropertyY!=null && PropertyY.Length < 5;
    },
    //properties to watch
    (p) => new { p.PropertyX, p.PropertyY }
 );
```

Answer (score -5):

This is what worked for me:  Put the CanExecute before the Command in the XAML.

Comment: I'm willing to eat the -3 without complaining.
I do wonder what I did wrong and would appreciate feedback letting me know if I was outright wrong, or what the problem is.

Comment: @mustakos I think it's too short and lacks code. Most answers should have example code.