# WPF Validation (IDataErrorInfo) with ICommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, idataerrorinfo

I use `ICommand` in the ViewModel to be able to add/remove items from collections etc.

I also have validation that belongs in the model classes to validate textboxes etc.

Is there a way I can use the two (`ICommand` in the ViewModel + the Validation in the model) to disable the button if a textbox has failed Validation? I ask because the `ICommand` exposes the `CanExecute` event so I guess it would be wise to use that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the idea right. Implement a `CanExecute` method that returns the result of your model validation so that when it fails, the button will be disabled.

Then, you must make sure that the `CanExecute` is called again when the validation conditions change - for instance, when a binding property has changed. In order to do so, [you may require more advanced implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340302/wpf-how-to-force-a-command-to-re-evaluate-canexecute-via-its-commandbindings) of `ICommand` such as [Prism's `DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx).