# How to requery 'CanExecute' of a single RoutedCommand?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, routed-commands

I need to refresh the `CanExecute` state of one or more (though by far not all) `RoutedCommand` objects.

I know that [you can update all commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340302/wpf-how-to-force-a-command-to-re-evaluate-canexecute-via-its-commandbindings) by using

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

Since this updates far more commands than necessary, calling this function is sometimes a performance problem in my application.

My initial hope was that calling `CanExecute()` manually would also raise the event if the state changed, but this is not the case.

When looking at the reference source then, the `CanExecuteChanged` does not seem to be accessible for derived classes to provide some kind of extension to the `RoutedCommand` class that allows raising the event manually.

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Any ideas how I could implement such a mechanism? I know about `DelegateCommand`, but I need a routed command, so I don't think this class can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom `RoutedCommand`, reimplement `ICommand` and register an additional event yourself. Note that using `new` is supposedly safe here because WPF will use an `ICommand` reference to call `CanExecuteChanged`.

```
public class MyRoutedCommand : RoutedCommand, ICommand
{
    private event EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = _canExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public new event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            _canExecuteChanged += value;
            base.CanExecuteChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _canExecuteChanged -= value;
            base.CanExecuteChanged -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

You should be aware that while WPF will use a `WeakEventManager` to register to this event, others devs might not. Since routed commands are usually defined as static fields, this could be a potential memory leak. You could implement a weak event manager to prevent this.

Comment: Heh, nice one. I tried almost the same code myself, but it only works if you add `ICommand` to the interface list which I did not consider. Thx.