# WPF button is disabled by default and I can't enable it again

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Since some people can't be bothered to click on a link, here's all ~80 lines of XAML code for the window...

```
<Window x:Class="TollLicenser.Views.LicenseView"
        x:Name="wdw"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TollLicenser.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="License View" Height="300" Width="300"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TollLicenser.ViewModels"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:LicenseViewModel}"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Margin="8">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Shadows.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ToggleButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 8 8 8" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 8 8 8" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 8 8 8" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=CountryCode}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHeadlineTextBlock}">
            Managing a License
        </TextBlock>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Country Code</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="CountryCode" Text="{Binding CountryCode}"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Plaza Name</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TollPlazaName}"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Start Date</Label>
        <DatePicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0">End Date</Label>
        <DatePicker Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate}"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0">Max Users</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MaxUsers}"/>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="6" Height="5" />

        <Button Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Content="Save" Margin="8" IsEnabled="True" IsDefault="True"
                Command="{Binding SaveLicenseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=wdw}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Basically the problem is that the damn button (seen below) is disabled even from the time the window opens...

This seems to bind correctly to [the ViewModel](https://hastebin.com/nubecemoqa.cs).

Only things in the viewmodel that have anything really to do with the button is the command and the method it executes as below:

```
public ICommand SaveLicenseCommand => new AwaitableDelegateCommand<Window>(SaveLicense);
private async Task SaveLicense(Window wdw)
{
    _model.Id = Id;
    _model.CountryCode = Encryption.Encrypt(CountryCode);
    _model.EndDate = Encryption.Encrypt(EndDate.ToString());
    _model.MaxUsers = Encryption.Encrypt(MaxUsers.ToString());
    _model.StartDate = Encryption.Encrypt(StartDate.ToString());
    _model.TollPlazaName = Encryption.Encrypt(TollPlazaName);

    // LYTODO Post the model to the web service.
    if (_model.Id != 0)
    {
        // Editing a license.
        await _apiHelper.PutLicenseAsync(_model);
        await _licenses.Load(); // Reload licenses with the updated item.
    }
    else
    {
        // Adding a license.
        await _apiHelper.PostLicenseAsync(_model);
    }

    wdw.Close();
}
```

I don't have the faintest idea why the button is disabled or what other information to provide so please comment if there's more that you need and I will include it.

Why is the window opening with the button disabled?

Comment: give your xaml code

Comment: @RackM the whole window's markup is linked on the first line of the question.

Comment: That's usually a bug in the `ICommand` implmemenation.  Try calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340302/wpf-how-to-force-a-command-to-re-evaluate-canexecute-via-its-commandbindings

Comment: @MickyD incidentally the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` issue appears to actually have been the bug. I copied my code from a different project which correctly implements the same model and now the button isn't disabled. Don't know what mistake I made this time though...

Comment: Don't worry.  I've had it happen to me a few times too.  Can never work out the exact reason even though the same class is being used elsewhere fine

Comment: How is your `AwaitableDelegateCommand` class implemented?