# Why does BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted not update GUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I already searched the forum but no asked question fits to my problem I think ...

I use a BackgroundWorker to handle a very time consuming operation. After this operation finishes a button should be set to enabled so that the user can perform another operation.

I'm using WPF and I'm following the MVVM pattern, so I have no direct access to this button. I have to call a method in the BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted event handler which sets a Property, representing the buttons enabled-state, to true.

That all works fine except one thing: The button is only redrawn after I e.g. click into the window (or maximize the window, ...). Thats very annoying and took me the whole day to get rid of this behaviour but I can't find a solution ...

The BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted event handler looks like this:

```
    void fileLoadBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        SetButtonToEnabled(); }
```

Has anyone any idea how to fix this issue?

Edit:

The button is bound to a command:

```
<Button Name="btnLoadTargetFile" Command="{Binding Path=LoadTargetCommand}" .../>
```

This command is a RelayCommand as Smith stated in his blog (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and looks like this:

```
public RelayCommand LoadTargetCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (loadTargetCommand == null)
            {
                loadTargetCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.OnRequestLoadFile(BusinessLogic.CustomTypes.TreeType.Target), param => this.CanLoadTarget);
            }
            return loadTargetCommand;
        }
        set { loadTargetCommand = value; }
    }
```

this.CanLoadTarget is set to true by the SetButtonToEnabled(); method

Edit 2:

the following code 'works':

```
fileLoadBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(argumentList);
while(fileLoadBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
SetButtonToEnabled();
```

but that is some sort of really dangerous and ugly code ...

Comment: When you set the property to true do you raise the `PropertyChanged` event (ie. does your viewmodel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly)?

Comment: If I call that method after fileLoadBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() everything works fine, so I don't think that is the problem?!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using any WMI modifications to the form's shape or border (border color, etc.)?

Comment: klausbyskov is probably correct / has a good point. So - DO you implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly? :)

Comment: @md5sum: no I don't!
@benjamin: yes I do ;-) ... i ported the code from a non-threading environment to the current, everything worked fine before we started to use the BackgroundWorker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Althought it doesnt explain your problem, you could try to add

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

or

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

to the end of your SetButtonToEnabled function call (after you set the button Enabled to true).  It looks like the backgroundworker is calling the Complete event, but the GUI is not refreshing.

[Here](http://pavanpodila.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9C9E888164859398!246.entry) is a complete example using the Backgroundworker in WPF.  You might want to take a look at it and make sure you stuff looks the same.

You could also take a look at [Asynchronous Threading with Background Worker Object](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=93).  This is a good example of using the Dispatcher and the Backgroundworker

The [WPF Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) is another great source to check out.

Comment: thanks for your comment! my code looks like the example except that I have no direct access to the buttons because of the MVVM pattern I use

Comment: Could you post the code for SetButtonToEnabled.  I dont think its a problem with backgroundworker, since you mentioned that Complete does get called.  Its probably something you are doing on the main thread.  What are you doing while the process is running in the background?

Comment: You might want to check out InvalidateRequerySuggested: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx Try adding this to the end of SetButtonToEnabled

Comment: This post might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783104/refresh-wpf-command

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, the call of CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably has nothing to do with the BackgroundWorker. If you call the `SetButtonToEnabled` method directly from the main thread you will probably see the same behavior. Replace the call to `RunWorkerAsync` with one to `SetButtonToEnabled` to test this.

A couple of the commenters suggested that you look at your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation this sounds like good advice.

Comment: thanks for your answer! If i call SetButtonToEnabled in the main thread everything works fine ...

Comment: Can you confirm that the RunWorkerCompleted event is being raised? Does a breakpoint that you set there get hit?

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of is to confirm that the event handler is being executed on the main thread.

Comment: In SetButtonToEnabled, check the Button's InvokeRequired Property to see if its true

Comment: Actually for WPF, looks like you check the Dispatcher, so something like this: btnRefresh.Dispatcher.CheckAccess().  See this post: http://www.diranieh.com/NET_WPF/Threading.htm

Comment: I think that the Debug Location Toolbar should show you which thread that you are on. Access it via View | Toolbars | Debug Location