# How can I refresh the UI in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm, refresh

My project is based on the MVVM pattern.

I have built a tree view that shows my file system.
Each folder has a checkbox for selecting the current folder.
The selection process is taking some time so, while the operation runs, there is a button which is disabled and at the end of the operation I`m enabling the button.

My problem is that when the button gets "disabled" I see it immediately. However, when the button is going back to the enabled mode I must do some action (like mouse click) to see the button enabled.

How can I make sure that the UI will be updated immediately after the button is enabled?

These are my buttons:

```
<Button Content="&lt;- Back" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="80" Height="25"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanMoveToPreviousPage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Command="{Binding Path=NavigateBackCommand, IsAsync=True}" />

<Button Content="{Binding ButtonNextCaption}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="80" Height="25"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanMoveToNextPage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Command="{Binding Path=NavigateNextCommand, IsAsync=True}" />
```

In my **ViewModel** I added this code:

```cs
public bool CanMoveToNextPage
{
    get
    {
        return this.CurrentPage != null && this.CurrentPage.CanMoveNext;
    }
    set
    {
        if (CurrentPage != null)
        {
            this.CurrentPage.CanMoveNext = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CanMoveToNextPage");
        }
    }
}

public bool CanMoveToPreviousPage
{
    get { return 0 < this.CurrentPageIndex && CurrentPage.CanMoveBack; }
    set
    {
        if (CurrentPage != null)
        {
            this.CurrentPage.CanMoveBack = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CanMoveToPreviousPage");
        }
    }
}
```

The UI update happens just after I execute a mouse click or any keystroke.

This is the code of the action that is disabling and enabling the buttons:

```cs
void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DecrementDoneCounter();
    if (ThreadSafeCouner == 0)//means all bg workers are done
    {
        UIlimitation(true);
    }
}

private int ThreadSafeCouner; // check how many bgworkers run
public void IncrementDoneCounter() { Interlocked.Increment(ref ThreadSafeCouner); }
public void DecrementDoneCounter() { Interlocked.Decrement(ref ThreadSafeCouner); }


void bg_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    IncrementDoneCounter();
    UIlimitation(false);
    ((bgArguments)e.Argument).SelectedDirectory.CanSelected = false;
    MarkItems(((bgArguments)e.Argument).SelectedDirectory, ((bgArguments)e.Argument).IsSelect);
    ((bgArguments)e.Argument).FreeWorkerAllocation();
    ((bgArguments)e.Argument).SelectedDirectory.CanSelected = true;
}

//this is the enabling action which execute the propeties setters at the upper part of this post
private static void UIlimitation(bool limit)
{
    MainWindowViewModel.Instance.CanMoveToNextPage = limit;
    MainWindowViewModel.Instance.CanMoveToPreviousPage = limit;
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: try this.UpdateLayout() or ButtonsParent.UpdateLayout()

Comment: When your operation is done are you raising the `OnPropertyChanged` event for your concerned properties responsible for enabling/disabling the button?

Comment: When i done I`m changing the enabled property but Set{...} and the Set{} include the OnPropertyChanged event. When I try to debug everything works perfevt and the button get enabled without click. I can figure it out what is the problem

Comment: I added the code when i raise the event. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

You can adjust on your control  `Binding mode TwoWay` and define `triggers with PropertyChanged`

```
{Binding ElementName=.., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Comment: I did it but the problem has still exists.

Comment: MVVM model should  implement INotifyPropertyChanged, in order to send notify to controls

Answer (score 4):

OK I found a solution.
I tried everything without success and eventually I found this thread:
[Refresh WPF Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783104/refresh-wpf-command)

I have used `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`

And its works.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code example of how you might set up your ViewModel with the INotifyPropertyChanged method of sending messages to update the UI:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /******************************************************/
    /* Property that you have created two-way binding for */
    /******************************************************/
    private double _myProperty
    public double MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            _myProperty = value;

            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Members
}
```

Comment: Make sure the value of OnNotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty"); is right.