# RelayCommand CanExecute behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have following command:

```
<Button x:Name="bOpenConnection" Content="Start Production"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        Height="30" Width="120" Margin="10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Command="{Binding Path=StartProductionCommand}"/>
```

```
StartProductionCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenConnection, CanStartProduction);

private bool CanStartProduction()
{
   return LogContent != null && !_simulationObject.Connected;
}
```

`CanStartProduction` is checked only when I re-size the UI and not updated on the fly.
Any idea why it's not updated every time they change the values ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `CommandManager` has no way of knowing that the command depends on `LogContent` and `_simulationObject.Connected`, so it can't reevaluate `CanExecute` automatically when these properties change.

You can explicitly request a reevaluation by calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`. Note that it will reevaluate `CanExecute` for *all* commands; if you want to refresh only one, you need to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event on the command itself by calling `StartProductionCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged`.

Comment: can you give an example or post link how to use this please? I mean where do you call this?

Comment: @batmaci, you just call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` when you want the `CanExecute` of your command to be reevaluated

Answer (score 0):

You can call RaiseCanExecuteChanged in the For example PropertyChanged Eventhandler.

Command states are not refreshed very often.

Sometime ago I read a good article about it. I will post it later on.

see also http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/

see also [Refresh WPF Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783104/refresh-wpf-command)